# How to get current connection parameters (connection interval, etc.)

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-8.1

Is it possible to get current BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) connection parameters (connection interval, etc.) for the paired device from C# application running on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

No. But if you write the firmware for the peripheral, you could have it notify the central whenever the parameters are updated.